# Backbone.js and jQuery Mobile - accessing router function from view

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to handle all the page routing/transitions in the router file then reference those functions in the view file from other functions.  I have tried a few methods but can't access any router functions from the view.  The error Im getting is AppRouter is undefined.

```
**Code snippet from router.js:**

...
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

routes: {
  '': 'showDefault',
  'index': 'showDefault',
  'cart': 'showCart',
  '*actions': 'defaultAction'
 },

showCart: function(actions) {
  console.log('show cart called');
  this.changePage(cartView);
},
changePage: function(page) {
  $('body').append($(page.el));
  $.mobile.changePage($(page.el), { changeHash: true, transition: 'slide' });
}
...

**Code snippet from default page view js**
...
events: {
  'click #showCart': 'cartPage',
},
cartPage: function(action) {
  $.AppRouter.showCart;
},
...
```

Comment: `$.AppRouter`, there is the problem.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the appropriate href to fire off the function on the router, eg 'cart'? If you want to talk between views, using your own instance of Backbone.Events and subscribing/publishing design works well. Sorry if I misunderstood what you are trying to acheive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initialize the router, you had to do something like:

```
new AppRouter();
```

You need to find that bit of code and rewrite into something you can access globally:

```
window.appRouter = new AppRouter();
```

You can then access your router like this:

```
appRouter.showCart();  # instead of $.AppRouter.showCart
```